# js get class of calling object in function

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

I have a structure similar to this:

```
 class Person {
        greet() {
            console.log(this.constructor.name)
        }
    }

    class User extends Person {
    }

    let user = new User()
    user.greet()
```

Unfortunately it prints `window` for `this.constructor.name` instead of `User`.
Is there some other way to get the actual class Name?

Actual code:

```
static MeteorMethod(target: MeteorModel, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        let constructor = target.constructor
        let className = target.constructor.name
        let methodName = key
        let method = descriptor.value
        let meteorMethodName = MeteorModelDecorators.generateMethodName(constructor, methodName)
        MeteorModelDecorators.MeteorMethodClasses[className] = target

        if(Meteor.isServer) {
            Meteor.methods({
                [meteorMethodName]: (modelClassName: string, modelProps: object, ...args: any[]) => {
                    let model = new MeteorModelDecorators.MeteorMethodClasses[modelClassName](modelProps)
                    method.apply(model, args)
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            descriptor.value = async function(...args: any[]) {
                // here I expect this to be Book, but I get Window
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    Meteor.call(meteorMethodName, this.constructor.name, this, args, (error: any, result: any) => {
                        if(error) reject(error)
                        resolve(result)
                    })
                })
            }
        }
    }

class MeteorModel {
    @MeteorMethod
    save() {
        console.log('save')
    }
}

class Book extends MeteorModel {
}

let book = new Book()
book.save()
```

Comment: Use `new Promise((resolve, reject) => Meteor.call(...` instead of `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { Meteor.call(...`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this part:

```
descriptor.value = async function(...args: any[]) {
            // here I expect this to be Book, but I get Window
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                Meteor.call(meteorMethodName, this.constructor.name, this, args, (error: any, result: any) => {
                    if(error) reject(error)
                    resolve(result)
                })
            })
        }
```

It needs to be this:

```
descriptor.value = async function(...args: any[]) {
            // With the arrow function, should be Book
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Meteor.call(meteorMethodName, this.constructor.name, this, args, (error: any, result: any) => {
                    if(error) reject(error)
                    resolve(result)
                })
            })
        }
```

The function you were passing to the `Promise` constructor was setting up a new context, by using the arrow function you pick up the `this` context from the surrounding method.